# How to calculate interest while react native app is closed

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm trying to build an app that has investments in it, I want to be able to calculate interest for some investments so for example if an investment has a 5% APY, I want the user's investment to increase by 5 % at the end of a month. so for example if the user puts an asset worth 100$, after 29 days it remains 100$ but on the 30th day it becomes 105$. I want this to be automatic (to happen even if the app is closed) but I'm unable to find a way to do that. If i use any time interval functions in my code, it does not run while the app is closed. Thank you for the help.

Comment: remember the last calculate data, get the calculate dates and  with the diff. between last calc date and today when starting the app.

Comment: You don't need to do it when the app is closed.  Calculating the interest takes a tiny fraction of a second. When the user opens the app you can calculate the interest based on the elapsed time and display it.

Comment: oh true I didn't think of that! thank you so much, that will definitely solve my problem